# Can't get custom ASP MVC 4 WebAPI MembershipProvider to be called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, membership-provider

I'm trying to wire up a custom membership privider in ASP MVC 4 WebAPI but I cannot figure out how to replace the current provider.  I've put a breakpoint in the constructor of the provider and it never lands on it.  Running the test below gives me a "401 Unauthorized" message on the GetResponse call so SOMETHING is trying to validate the request.  Where am I going wrong?  Nearly this identical code runs in ASP MVC 4 site (not WebAPI).

I know the general logic in the test is working because the test succeeds if i remove the Authorize attribute.

This is my WebConfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<profile enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership  defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" 
         type="CustomWebApiMembershipProvider" 
         applicationName="AppName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyWebApiRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyWebApiRoleProvider" type="CustomWebApiRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This is my provider.

```
public class CustomWebApiMembershipProvider: MembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return password.Contains("please");
    }

    public CustomWebApiMembershipProvider()
    {
        var x = "hello";
    }

}
```

This is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestApiSecureController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"CustomWebApi Secured Access"};
    }
}
```

and this is my test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Authorize_WhenApiKeyProvided_ReturnsValidResponse()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4011/api/TestApiSecure") as HttpWebRequest;
        AddAuthorizationInfo(request, "username", "pleaseLetMeIn");

        //we keep timing out when stepping through in debug, so set huge timeout
        request.Timeout = 100000;

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("CustomWebApi"));
    }
    private void AddAuthorizationInfo(HttpWebRequest request, string username, string password)
    {
        var usernamePwString = username + ":" + password;
        var authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(usernamePwString));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + authInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like forms authentication requires some cookies magic, that isn't handled by an HttpWebRequest. You'll need to create your own Authorize attribute - check out : http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/